# drupal table with the edit link

Tags: drupal

I have a table in drupal which displays all the content from a table. I have added an edit link to each record . This link should take the user to the input form which has the values populated in it corresponding to the record. RIght now it is just populating the form with the last row.

For a row x, i need the form populated with the values for record x.

The table is created as

```
function _MYMODULE_sql_to_table($sql) {

     $html = "";

    // execute sql
    $resource = db_query($sql);

    // fetch database results in an array
    $results = array();
    while ($row = db_fetch_array($resource)) {
      $results[] = $row;
      $email = $row['p1'];
      $comment = $row['p2'];
    }


    // ensure results exist
    if (!count($results)) {
    $html .= "Sorry, no results could be found.";
    return $html;    
  }

    // create an array to contain all table rows
    $rows = array();
    // get a list of column headers
    $columnNames = array_keys($results[0]);

    // loop through results and create table rows
    foreach ($results as $key => $data) {

      // create row data
       $row = array(

   'edit' => l(t('Edit'),"admin/content/test/$p1/$p2/Table1",     $options=array()),);

      // loop through column names
      foreach ($columnNames as $c) {
       $row[] = array(
        'data' => $data[$c],
        'class' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $c)),
        );
      }

      // add row to rows array
      $rows[] = $row;

     }

    // loop through column names and create headers
    $header = array();
    foreach ($columnNames as $c) {
     $header[] = array(
      'data' => $c,
      'class' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $c)),
      );
    }

    // generate table html
    $html .= theme('table', $header, $rows);

    return $html;

  }

   // then you can call it in your code...
   function _MYMODULE_some_page_callback() {

    $html = "";

    $sql = "select * from {contactus}";

    $html .= _MYMODULE_sql_to_table($sql);

    return $html;
  }
   function display(){
    $results = array();
 $html = "";
    $resource  = db_query("select * from contactus");
 $output = '';
 while($row = db_fetch_array($resource)){
    $results[] = $row;
 }
 if(!count($results)){
   $html.= "Unable to display table";
   return $html;
          }
   $rows = array();
   $columnNames = array_keys($results[0]);

         foreach($results as $key=>$data){
       $row = array();
      foreach($columnNames as $c){
       $row = array(
      'data' => $data[$c],
           'class' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $c)),
    );
    }
    $rows[] = $row;
 }
 $header = array();
 foreach($columnNames as $c){
 $header[] = array(
      'data' => $c,
      'class' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $c)),
    );
 }

 $html .= theme('table', $header, $rows);

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly? And if you need to store data in Drupal, why don't you use the node system or the data module (http://drupal.org/project/data)?

Comment: I can successfully save data using the $node system using node_save(). But in this case I am not using $node. It is a form which creates records in a custom table. I simply need to populate the form. There are 2 methods in drupal (i) drupal_execute  (ii) form_set_value which allow to do so. BUt I am getting error when i use either. So a working example would be helpful. Sorry, that is out of the scope of this question. But that is my main issue. I was able to create the edit link for this table and redirect it to the form. THanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have `$rows = array();` appear *before* your `while` loop. What you're doing is essentially destroying the array and redeclaring it as an empty array on each pass. This is why only the last row is appearing for you.